# LocalStorage - Remove item by value and not key?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

Ok so I have a JSON like this stocked in LocalStorage :

```
[{"pseudo":"Lucia","id":2},{"pseudo":"Romain","id":1}]
```

I searched how I can remove one item and I only find this :

```
storage.removeItem(keyName);
```

But, correct me if I am wrong, if I use this will remove all the value with keyName "pseudo" if I do storage.removeItem(pseudo);

How can I only remove `{"pseudo":"Romain","id":1}` from the json and keep `{"pseudo":"Lucia","id":2}` ?

Thank you.

Comment: That is the issue with storing complex objects in localstorage. You will have to read the entire JSON object, parse it, modify it, stringify it then save the modified object. You should be looking into IndexDB if your wanting complex data objects and querying.

Comment: (1.) Get the data from `LocalStorage` (2.) Parse it (3.) Splice the `object` from parsed array (4.) Again `stringify` the data (5.) Assign it back to `LocalStorage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localstorage only supports string values, so you need to parse data.

```
    var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("keyName"));

    // here you need to make a loop to find the index of item to delete
    var indexToRemove = 1;

    //remove item selected, second parameter is the number of items to delete 
    storedNames.slice(indexToRemove, 1);

   // Put the object into storage
   localStorage.setItem('keyName', JSON.stringify(storedNames));
```

Comment: I don't understand where you remove the item, I tried but localstorage doesn't change

Comment: the .slice method removes items from an array

Comment: storedNames and storedName are the same (you forget one "s" or it is normal ^^) ? or storedNames is the whole json ?

Comment: i forget the s, that variable is storing all the data of the localstorage item

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage comes with a *length* so you know how many values are being stored and a method *key* which lets you find a key at an index.

```
function removeLocalStorageValues(target) {
    let i = localStorage.length;
    while (i-- > 0) {
        let key = localStorage.key(i);
        if (localStorage.getItem(key) === target) {
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the OP meant to modify an element in a stored array, not to delete the entire localstorage item. The title and question content seem to differ however.

Answer (score 0):

localstorage only supports string values, so you need to parse data.
( replaced slice to splice )

```
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("keyName"));

// here you need to make a loop to find the index of item to 
delete
var indexToRemove = 1;

//remove item selected, second parameter is the number of items 
to delete 
storedNames.splice(indexToRemove, 1);

// Put the object into storage  
localStorage.setItem('keyName', JSON.stringify(storedNames));
```