# LocalStorage remove item with specific Value

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I am trying to remove a single value from my localStorage array. The value I am trying to remove is `30`

localStorage Values: `["70","30"]`

```
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage["favorite"]);
for (var i =0; i< items.length; i++) {
    var item = JSON.parse(items[i]);
    if (item == 30) {
      items.slice(i);
      break;
    }
}

localStorage.setItem("favorite", items);
```

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to search for "javascript, splice"

Comment: pos dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366923/localstorage-remove-item-by-value-and-not-key

Comment: `JSON.parse(items[i])` is redundant as `i` is an integer.